# Symfony 2 - can't save form with collections

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am struggling with some symfony 2 form problem for a while. When trying to save my form I am getting following message:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Org\CoreBundle\Entity\CustomLists#customListElements' that was not
>   configured to cascade persist operations for entity:
>   Org\CoreBundle\Entity\CustomListElement@000000007db26fee000000007e19f46a.
>   To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on
>   this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in
>   the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

I have called persist() method on collection elements and added cascade={"persist"} inside my entity, what was recommended in similar threads here, but it didn't help.

CustomLists.php:

```
 /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CustomListElement", mappedBy="customList", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $customListElements;

/**
     * Add customListElement
     *
     * @param \Org\CoreBundle\Entity\CustomListElement $customListElement
     *
     * @return CustomLists
     */
    public function addCustomListElement(\Org\CoreBundle\Entity\CustomListElement $customListElement)
    {
        $this->customListElements[] = $customListElement;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove customListElement
     *
     * @param \Org\CoreBundle\Entity\CustomListElement $customListElement
     */
    public function removeCustomListElement(\Org\CoreBundle\Entity\CustomListElement $customListElement)
    {
        $this->customListElements->removeElement($customListElement);
    }
```

CustomListElement.php:

```
 /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CustomLists", inversedBy="customListElements", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="custom_list", referencedColumnName="id_custom_list", nullable=false)
     */
    private $customList;

  /**
     * Set customList
     *
     * @param \Org\CoreBundle\Entity\CustomLists $customList
     * 
     * @return CustomListElement
     */

    public function setCustomList(\Org\CoreBundle\Entity\CustomLists $customList = null)
    {
        $this->customList = $customList;

        return $this;
    }
```

CustomListType.php:

```
    $builder->add('customListElements', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new CustomListElementType(),
            'label' => false,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
    ));
```

Contoller:

```
   if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        $customListElements = $data->getCustomListElements();
         foreach($customListElements as $element){
            $element->setCustomList($data);
            $em->persist($element);
            $em->flush();
        }       

        $em->persist($data);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

I have really no idea, what I am doing wrong. I would by thankful for any helpful answers.

EDIT: 
Here is my form code:

```
{% extends 'OrganizerBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

{% block header %}
{{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="col col-md-8">
        <div class="panel panel-success custom-list-form">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">{{ title }}</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            {{ form_start(form) }}

                {{ form_row(form.listName) }}

                <h3>Elementy</h3>

                <ul class="elements" 
                data-prototype="{% filter escape %}{% include 'OrganizerBundle:CustomLists:elementTemplate.html.twig'  %}{% endfilter %}">
                {% for tag in form.customListElements %}
                    <li>
                    <div class="custom-list-element">
                        <div id="customList_customListElements___name__">
                            <div>
                                 {{ form_row(tag.elementName) }}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                {{ form_row(tag.elementDescription) }}
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="customList_customListElements___name___elementOrder"
                                name="customList[customListElements][__name__][elementOrder]" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="element-buttons">
                            <i class="fa fa-times remove-element" title="{{ 'Usuń'|trans }}" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
                        </div>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}

                </ul>
                {% do form.customListElements.setRendered %}
                <div class="form-buttons">{{ form_widget(form.zapisz) }}</div>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var $collectionHolder;

    var addElemText = '{{ 'Dodaj element'|trans }}';
    var $newElementButton = $('<a href="#" class="add_element_link"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">'+ 
            addElemText +'</button></a>');
    var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>');

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        $collectionHolder = $('.elements');

        $newElementButton.insertBefore($collectionHolder);
        $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

        $newElementButton.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            addElementForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
        });

        function addElementForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {

            var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');
            var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');
            var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

            $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

            var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
            $collectionHolder.append($newFormLi);
        }

    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

and my elementTemplate.html.twig prototype template:

```
<div class="listBox" data-pk="{{ element.idCustomList }}">
    <input type="checkbox" class="list-checkbox"/>
    <div class="custom-list-name">{{ element.listName }}</div>
    <div class="list-elem-count">{{ 'elementów:'|trans ~ '...' }}</div>
    <div class="list-elem-created">
        <span class="created-text">{{ 'utworzono:'|trans }}</span>
        <div class="date-created">{{ '...'  }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2 :
When I am doing `doctrine:schema:validate`, there is also an error:

> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Org\CoreBundle\Entity\CustomLists'
>   mapping is invalid:
>   * The field Org\CoreBundle\Entity\CustomLists#customListElements is on the inverse side of a bi-directional relationship, but the specified
>   mappedBy association on the target-entity
>   Org\CoreBundle\Entity\CustomListElement#customList does not contain
>   the required 'inversedBy="customListElements"' attribute.

Comment: You'll need to specified the `inversedBy` if you are using `mappedBy`. That may explain the issue. And try adding the `$customListElement->setCustomList($this)` in your `addCustomListElement()`, which is good practice even if it's not necessary.

Comment: Also, you should almost never need more than one flush() per request. And if you are flushing the CustomListElements before you persist/flush a new CustomList, then Doctrine won't have a CustomList ID to put on the CustomListElements table.

Answer (score 1):

Did you added this line in the constructor of CustomLists.php :

```
$customListElements = new ArrayCollection();
```

Change cascade to all in OneToMany declaration.

```
/**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CustomListElement", mappedBy="customList", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $customListElements;
```

It is not necessary to read all $customListElements and add it manually. Doctrine will do that automatically because he know that CustomLists had a relationship with CustomListElement due to the OneToMany.

You can change your controller like that :

```
$entity = new CustomLists();
$form = $this->createForm(new CustomListType(), $entity);
$form->handleRequest($request); 

if ($form->isValid()) {
       $em->persist($entity);
       $em->flush();    
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Unfortunately, after doing all of the above, it still occurs

Comment: Try using `$this->customListElements->add($customListElement);` in your `addCustomListElement()` method.

Comment: Did you use javascript code to display your collection in your template?

Comment: @Ryan - still the same. I am using javascript with my own prototype template to add new elements.

Comment: @Tungenius - Yes, I have edited my post and placed a code there

Comment: Why did you specify @ORM\JoinColumn(name="custom_list", referencedColumnName="id_custom_list", nullable=false)
Let doctrine generate it by him self like this :
@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)

Comment: Or verify your referencedColumnName="id_custom_list" maybe you should change it like this : referencedColumnName="custom_list_id"